# Converting U+ unicode to escaped unicode

Tags: r, unicode

This prints nicely in R:

```
> cat('\u0052')
R
```

This does not:

```
> Unicode::as.u_char('0052')
[1] U+0052
> Unicode::as.u_char('0052') |> cat()
82
```

How do you convert output of `as.u_char` to the `\u0000` format?

Comment: You are not looking for the letter itself `intToUtf8(as.hexmode("0052"))`? Would this be useful `parse(text = sprintf("'\\u%s'", "0052"))`? What is the end-goal?

Comment: I tend to dislike eval/parse tricks, but `eval(parse(text = paste0('"\\u', "0052", '"'), '\n'))` works here.

Comment: Note that the number "0052" is a hexadecimal number, so it's numeric value is 82. If you do `intToUtf8(82)` you get back R. Do you want to get back "R" or "\u0052" as a string? Using base R you can do `intToUtf8(base::strtoi(paste0('0x', '0052')))` to convert the hex value

Comment: Actually I may be mistaken, and `intToUtf8(as.hexmode("0052"))` is exactly right.

Comment: Yes `identical(intToUtf8(as.hexmode('0052')), '\u0052')` is TRUE. Good if someone can post as an answer.

Comment: @r2evans No need for `eval()`, this also works without (except that by default `parse()` returns an expression, so you either need to extract the first element, or you use `str2lang()` instead of `parse()`).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the number "0052" is a hexadecimal number, so it's numeric value is 82. If you do intToUtf8(82) you get back R. The easiest way to converting "0052" from hex to decimal is to use `as.hexmode`. Note that all these evaluate to true

```
identical("R", '\u0052')
identical("R", intToUtf8(82))
identical("R", intToUtf8(as.hexmode("0052")))
```